# Estimation Quote on realism vs optimism - does it exist?

Tags: planning, estimation

I could have sworn I read a quote by Steve McConnell or perhaps Fred Brooks about teams that make conservative estimates and pessimistic deadlines but meet them every time garner more trust and respect than pretty much every other kind. But, I couldn't find it. Maybe I imagined it.

Does anyone know if such a quote exists?

Comment: Questions seeking links to off-site resources are generally considered off-topic. It's very much on the bubble, though, and could potentially be edited to fit within the guidelines defined in our Help Center.

Answer (score 6):

I don't find quote of Steve McConnell about conservative estimates and pessimistic deadlines, but I know his words about optimistic estimates:

> Considering that optimism is a near-universal fact of human nature,
>   software estimates are sometimes undermined by what I think of as a
>   Collusion of Optimists. Developers present estimates that are
>   optimistic. Executives like the optimistic estimates because they
>   imply that desirable business targets are achievable. Managers like
>   the estimates because they imply that they can support upper
>   management's objectives. And so the software project is off and
>   running with no one ever taking a critical look at whether the
>   estimates were well founded in the first place.

By reading this, it's not hard to understand, why he like conservative estimates more.